# Best way to replace comma with a dot jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field where I need to replace the comma `,` with a dot `.`
What is the best way to do this?

HTML form-

```
<input type="text" id="field_ce5yi-other_2-otext" class="frm_other_input frm_pos_none" name="item_meta[other][96]" value="" style="background-color: pink;">
```

The Jquery (my first attempt)

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").keyup(function(){
        $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").text($("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").text().replace(','.''))
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you have extra `"` in your jQuery code and what issue you are facing right now?

Comment: So what's wrong with your way?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that we can quickly check.
Here's how:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there are a couple of syntax mistakes but the main issue is you're using `text()` when you need to use `val()` with it being an input.

Here's a working example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").on('keyup',function(){
    $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").val($("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").val().replace(',','.'))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field_ce5yi-other_2-otext" class="frm_other_input frm_pos_none" name="item_meta[other][96]" value="" style="background-color: pink;">
```

Answer (score 0):

fix the script:
use val() instead text()

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").keyup(function(){
                $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").val($("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").val().replace(',','.'));
    });
    });
 </script>
```

now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for replacing is a little different to what you had. Basically the following grabs the value of the input on the keyup, replacing all the instances of the comma (thats what the "g" does in the replace - g for global)  with a dot and then resets the value to the new string. Note that the comma is escaped (thats what the backslash is for).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").keyup(function(){
        var enteredText = $(this).val();
        var newText = enteredText.replace(/\,/g,'.');
        $(this).val(newText);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support ancient MSIE, simply do this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#field_ce5yi-other_2-otext").on('input', function() {
        var currValue = $(this).val().replace(/\,/g, '.');
        $(this).val(currValue);
    });
});
```

*(This will replace **all** occurrences of the `,` character to `.`)*